# How to set endpoint specific header value in Camel Multicast

Tags: apache-camel

I want to set the endpoint specific header value in Multicast component.

XML DSL as below:

```
<route>

<from uri="direct:testRoute"/>
<multicast strategyRef="MyAggregator" parallelProcessing="true">
<to uri="direct:call1"/> <!-- set the header MY_HEADER = "call_1" -->
<to uri="direct:call2/> <!-- set the header MY_HEADER = "call_2" -->
</multicast>

</route>
```

Basically in the response aggregation I want to know, to which service request this response belongs to.

I tried by doing this, but its not the correct way (parse exception):

```
<to uri="direct:call1"> 
      <setHeader headerName="MY_HEADER"><simple>call1</simple></setHeader>
 </to>
```

What I see from reading the documentation is that, multicast will copy the source Exchange and multicast each copy. So its a shallow copy of the Exchange and kind of reference shared between all the multicast recipient.

But here I am looking for specific header value for individual recipient.

How to do this? Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a header with the key Exchange.TO_ENDPOINT that you can see which of the 2 endpoints the response is from.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what I wanted.. let me start making the changes!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in the multicast route. But it should be simple in the direct route afterwards.

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:call1"/>
     <setHeader headerName="MY_HEADER"><simple>call1</simple></setHeader>
     .. do whatever
  </from>
</route>
```

otherwise, if call1 is used for other things and you cannot know when to put the header once in that route, make a simple prep-route:

```
<route>
   <from uri="direct:prepCall1"/>
     <setHeader headerName="MY_HEADER"><simple>call1</simple></setHeader>
     <to uri="direct:call1"/>
  </from>
</route>
```

As a third option, even though you cannot place DSL (xml or java) in the multicast list, you can supply an "onPrepareRef" processor bean that adds the headers to your exchange. But one processor will handle all multicast endpoints.

Comment: thanks for your response. I think I need to think more about my approach as I can not add call specific header value in Multicast list..